# Reducing an Equation to Standard Form

Tags: plotting, simplifying-expressions

I have to reduce x^2-y^2+z^2-4x-2z=0 to the standard form of a hyperboloid of one sheet using mathematica and I cannot figure out how to. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give more info about what you mean by "the standard form of a hyperboloid of one sheet"?

Answer (score 2):

You can typically find all the solutions of your equation to match a general form by using `Solve` using the standard form of the hyperboloid of $\frac{x^2}{A}+\frac{y^2}{B}-\frac{z^2}{C}$

```
Solve[x^2 - y^2 + z^2 - 4 x - 2 z == (x^2/A) + (y^2/B) - (z^2/C) && 
  x^2 - y^2 + z^2 - 4 x - 2 z == 0, {A, B, C}]
```

However, this gives no solutions `{}`. You can try `Reduce` instead.

```
Reduce[x^2 - y^2 + z^2 - 4 x - 2 z == (x^2/A) + (y^2/B) - (z^2/C) && 
  x^2 - y^2 + z^2 - 4 x - 2 z == 0, {A, B, C}]
```

And the resulting solutions are rather complex. It will give you solutions for A,B,C, but as you find those are complex and have many dependencies.

You can plot the result using Region Plot

```
RegionPlot3D[x^2 - y^2 + z^2 - 4 x - 2 z < 0, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, {z, -20, 20}]
```

[image]